# Cordova Google-analytics-plugin with ionic in Android does not work

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, google-analytics, ionic-framework

I have trouble with getting my cordova/ionic android app to work with google analytics. 
For now I have tried GAPlugin with anulartics without success, and now I am trying simpler setup with `https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin`

In my ionic angular app, I have added following code in

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {   

 if (typeof analytics !== 'undefined'){
          analytics.startTrackerWithId('UA-55MYNUMB8-1');
          analytics.trackView('testapmain');
          console.log("starting analytics");
          analytics.debugMode()
        }
    else
    {
      console.log("Google Analytics plugin could not be loaded.")
    }
}
```

and it seems to be workling correctly, following is output of `adb -s BH9XXXXJ0D logcat | grep GAV3`

looks like it connects to google analytics, sends message

```
V/GAV3    (12570): Thread[client_id_fetcher,5,main]: Storing clientId.
I/GAV3    (12703): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.
V/GAV3    (12570): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: connecting to Analytics service
V/GAV3    (12570): Thread[main,5,main]: service connected, binder: android.os.BinderProxy@4483eda8
V/GAV3    (12570): Thread[main,5,main]: bound to service
V/GAV3    (12570): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: connect: bindService returned true for Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START cmp=com.google.android.gms/.analytics.service.AnalyticsService (has extras) }
V/GAV3    (12570): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Loaded clientId
V/GAV3    (12570): Thread[main,5,main]: Connected to service
I/GAV3    (12570): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.
V/GAV3    (12570): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: putHit called
V/GAV3    (12570): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit to service   PATH: https:  PARAMS: v=1,  ul=en-us,  t=appview,  ht=1412010481966,  sr=1080x1776,  an=testa,  tid=UA-55215798-3,  aid=com.ionicframework.testa300342,  cid=05b7c4d9-b3b3-4ea8-9f04-dfa61c6853ec,  av=0.0.1,  _u=.KnoK-AL,  cd=testapmain,
```

but nothing shows up in google analytics. Google analytic property is set as Mobile App.

ionic is 2.5
cordova 3.6.3-0.2.13
android 4.4.4
phone xperia z1
javac 1.7.0_65  OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.2) (7u65-2.5.2-3~14.04)
on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit

Any idea what might be wrong? Or how to debug it more to see if google analytics is receiving my messages?

Comment: Have you tried remote debugging with Chrome?

Comment: no. Is there some interesting way how to peek into google analytics?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like it was my own wishful thinking at fault. While it is said in documentation that app data will appear in analytics only after 24 hours, I somehow thought that it does not apply to 'Real-time' tab. It does. After 24 hours, Realtime data shows up with delay of seconds, but not earlier.

Some answers in related questions claim the opposite. Do not take it for granted, as I did.

Comment: So do you mean I will be able to get first results into the 'Real-time' tab only after 24 hours?